# QA: Xfce4 Broken After Renaming User

Tags: xfce

I have just stumbled upon a problem with my arch xfce4 distro.

After renaming my user the *startx* command no longer worked.

```
usermod -m -d /home/new_user -l new_user -m old_user
```

The xorg error log stated that */home/old_user* could no longer be found.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem was relatively easy:

I had to remove (or move to a backup location) my *~/.cache/sessions*

```
mv ~/.cache/sessions ~/.cache/sessionsbak
```

PS: The ~/.cache directory is part of the XDG
specification: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Also thanks to the contributors of an old thread dating from 2012.

[https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/my-xfce-is-not-working-properly~~~-4175441572-print/](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/my-xfce-is-not-working-properly%7E%7E%7E-4175441572-print/)